# Upgrading Rails 2.3.5 Routes to 3.2.6 Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I just finished upgrading from rails 2.3.5 to rails 3.2.6, I'm using ruby 1.8.7 on Windows and my current routes are no longer working.  Can somebody please guide me on the new format for 3.2.6, I'm a bit confused on how match works.

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.resources :uom_conversions
  map.connect 'delete_old_data/delete_data', :controller => "items", :action => "delete_data"
  map.connect 'delete_old_data', :controller => "items", :action => "delete_old_data"
  map.connect 'pricelist_import', :controller => "items", :action => "pricelist_import"
  map.connect 'pricelist_import/match_pricelist_columns', :controller => "items", :action => "match_pricelist_columns"
  map.connect 'commit_pricelist', :controller => "items", :action => "commit_pricelist"
  map.connect 'pricelist_tool', :controller => "items", :action => "pricelist_tool"
  map.connect 'cross_reference_import', :controller => "items", :action => "cross_reference_import"
  map.connect 'commit_cross_references', :controller => "items", :action => "commit_cross_references"
  map.connect 'import_file/commit_import', :controller => "items", :action => "commit_import"
  map.connect 'import_file', :controller => "items", :action => "import_file"
  map.connect 'import_file/match_columns', :controller => "items", :action => "match_columns"
  map.connect 'set_default_matches', :controller => "items", :action => "set_default_matches"
  map.connect 'save_default_matches', :controller => "items", :action => "save_default_matches"
  map.connect 'search', :controller => "items", :action => "search"
  map.connect 'search/import_search_file', :controller => "items", :action => "import_search_file"
  map.connect 'search/import_search_file/pick_search_column', :controller => "items", :action => "pick_search_column"
  map.connect 'items/create_uom', :controller => "items", :action => "create_uom"
  map.connect 'items/remove_uom/:uom_id', :controller => "items", :action => "remove_uom"
  map.connect 'items/show_cross_references/:id', :controller => "items", :action => "show_cross_references"


  map.resources :items

  map.resources :vendors

  map.resources :manufacturers

  map.resources :sub_categories

  map.resources :categories

  map.resources :hospitals

  map.resources :ministry_organizations

  map.resources :agreements



  map.connect 'users/change_password', :controller => "users", :action => "change_password"
  map.connect 'users/update_password', :controller => "users", :action => "update_password"
  map.resources :users

  map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'login', :action => 'logout'
  map.logout '/switch_admin', :controller => 'login', :action => 'switch_admin'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map.resources :items` becomes `resources :items`

All lines matching this format:

```
map.connect 'delete_old_data/delete_data', :controller => "items", :action => "delete_data"
```

become

```
match 'delete_old_data/delete_data', :to => "items#delete_data"
```

This:

```
map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'login', :action => 'logout'
```

would become

```
match "/logout", :to => "login#logout", :as => :logout
```